# CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 5, saw 37

Tags: python, pandas

The following error is being generated in python V3.47 when using the `DataReader` function in `pandas.io.data` module.  For example after performing

```
from pandas.io.data import DataReader
```

and doing

```
prices = DataReader('AAPL','yahoo')
```

the following error is generated:

```
CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 5, saw 37
```

Has anyone encountered this recent error when downloading prices from Yahoo finance?  I could not find any comments online regarding this error message.  My guess is that Yahoo Finance has once again changed their data format for download.

Comment: Sorry what's your python version? v 3.47 seems a little bit weird.

Comment: If you update pandas to v 0.17 maybe [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/remote_data.html#remote-data-yahoo) tutorial might be helpful.

Comment: I can reproduce you're code without errors using python 2.7.10 and pandas 0.17.